# Is there a free way of unlocking an Android phone from a particular network?

Tags: sim-unlocking

I bought a cheap Android handset for development and it is an exclusive to a particular network.

I would like to unlock it so I can use an existing SIM card from another network. I've done some googling and it appears that there are many services online where you can get a code from supplying your IMEI number.

Firstly, can anyone elaborate on what the unlocking process involves, and secondly, is there any application that can do this process, or are you forced to pay someone to generate a code for you?

Comment: Specifying the carrier you are trying to unlock from may help.  Its not absolutely necessary to answer the question but it may help.

Comment: I know that T-mobile will unlock your phone after x days of service. http://support.t-mobile.com/doc/tm51885.xml

Comment: It's an orange pay as you go San Francisco handset. Thanks

Comment: There are also device-specific methods.  The Galaxy S has the unlock code stored on the device, for example.

Answer (score 1):

To unlock you phone for free you can root it. But it is at your own risk. I found [this guide](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-sim-unlock-samsung-galaxy-s4-gt-i9505-for-free/) but don't know if it works for you.

Comment: -1, the OP pointed out this - *It's an orange pay as you go San Francisco handset. Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

The Rooting method for the T-Mobile G2 / HTC Desire Z unlocks the SIM lock on the modem, but this is device specific.

Comment: Actually, for just about any HTC device, obtaining S-off removes the network lock.  The S flag is basically the master control for all "security", not just the bootloader.

Comment: -1, like the OP pointed out this dated Nov 2nd 2010 *It's an orange pay as you go San Francisco handset. Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late getting to this (7 years actually) but if you still have it and it's still carrier locked, call the phone carrier and ask them if they have any conditions