# Unlocking SIM card Huawei Ascend Y530

Tags: sim-unlocking, huawei, carriers

I recently bought `Huawei Ascend Y530` which is SIM-locked in a swiss provider, `swisscom` that is. I checked through the web to find how can a sim-locked phone be used with any sim, but surprisingly I couldn't find something usefull.

There are a lot of entries, about companies that give you an unlocking code, by providing them, the device's `IMEI`. Unfortunately this doesn't come free of charge let alone the questionable reability.

I contacted `Huawei` to provide me with the code, but they couldn't.

The most relevant information I could find was from [xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2754481), where someone can find a lot of information about rooting or unlocking bootloader but not on how to unlock the sim.

Another interesting question was [Is there a free way of unlocking an Android phone from a particular network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/is-there-a-free-way-of-unlocking-an-android-phone-from-a-particular-network). There, someone can unlock the phone just by giving the IMEI number. Rather sadly however, this app can only be used for a certain provider and a specific device.

I don't know if I factory-reset the phone will be unlocked or even rooting it.

Does anyone know how to unlock the phone, so as to use any sim card? Is there a way to get access to the SIM-unlocking code, just like it can happen with a lot of Samsung devices?

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with Huawei. You need to contact the carrier who you got the phone from.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that the carrier will charge me a great ammount of money, much more than to buy a new unlocked one! I am looking for something similat to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/is-there-a-free-way-of-unlocking-an-android-phone-from-a-particular-network